# Checking if a file exists in the App folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hey you lot (again), I was wondering if anyone knew a fast and easy way to see if
a file (namely a textfile), exists inside the App folder?

And how to handle an Error correctly if the file doesn't exist.

Help would be grand! :) ty!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want to do something similar to this:

```
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *pathToFile = [myBundle pathForResource:@"MyImage" ofType:@"jpg"];
if (pathToFile != nil) {
    NSLog(@"MyImage.jpg found in the App bundle.");
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle?language=objc for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for file existence with something like:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:aPath]) { ... }
```

Depending on what you're looking for, "aPath" might be something like:

```
NSString *aPath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample.txt"];
```

or

```
NSString *aPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"txt"];
```